# MySQL Count cols with multiple group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have a database table with translations. There are the columns ID, word, translation, source_language, target_language. I want to find out how many translations there are per word into another language.

I used this query:

```
SELECT word, count(translation) as number, source_language, target_language
FROM word_translations 
WHERE source_language = 'deu'
GROUP BY  word, target_language
```

The results seem strange to me, however, when I look at the total number of translations available per language, it makes no sense. A word can have different numbers of translations into multiple languages, so I think I can't use group by word.

Sample data:

- car - Auto - eng - deu
- car - pkw - eng - deu
- car - voiture - eng - fra
- car - vagon - eng - fra
- car - car - eng - fra
- car - coche - eng - spa

expected result:

- car - deu - 2
- car - fra - 3
- car - spa - 1

Comment: Your code seems fine, but I don't understand what you mean by: *The results seem strange to me*

Comment: Sorry, i have added sample data and expected result, i hope that helps to understand

Comment: @keschra . . . Your sample all has a source language of "eng", but your coede has "deu".

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out how many translations there are per word into another language.

If you just want to count the translations, you may want:

```
SELECT word, count(*) as number_translations,
       count(distinct target_language) as num_languages
FROM word_translations 
WHERE source_language = 'deu'
GROUP BY word, source_language;
```

Your query counts the number of translations into each target language.

Comment: It is important that translations are counted per word and per target language. For example, the word "car" can have 5 German, 2 French and 10 different Russian translations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is wrong.
It should be: `WHERE source_language = 'eng'`

```
SELECT word, count(translation) as number, source_language, target_language
FROM word_translations 
WHERE source_language = 'eng'
GROUP BY  word, target_language
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzJiytgw9DUqJjhunNEziV/0).
Results:

```
| word | source_language | target_language | number |
| ---- | --------------- | --------------- | ------ |
| car  | eng             | deu             | 2      |
| car  | eng             | fra             | 3      |
| car  | eng             | spa             | 1      |
```

If you want to calculate *how many translations there are per word* for all source languages then you must also `group by source_language` and remove the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT word, count(translation) as number, source_language, target_language
FROM word_translations 
GROUP BY word, source_language, target_language
```

Comment: this was just an example, i wan't to calculate it for multiple languages, sorry for that. But it looks like the rsults are right. I need to find out why they don't relate to the total number of translations per language.

Comment: If you want to calculate it for multiple languages then the code must be different. Is this what you want?